# Bluestacks restarts automatically

Tags: windows-7, bluestacks

Bluestacks keeps restarting in the background even if i close the app.HD-Agent.exe is in the memory and i have to open windows task manager to close it.Otherwise it keeps running and after few seconds other Bluestacks processes (HD-FrontEnd.exe) runs(using the cpu and memory).I understand from this that it is restarting itself even though i have closed it.Someone help me please.Thank you.(OS-Windows 7)

Comment: i can suggest you virtualbox with android 4.2 is much stable and resource effective (at least for me)

Comment: here i tested 4.4 rc2 as more stable http://www.android-x86.org/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlueStacks also has a few services. Stop these and new processes will not launch.

Comment: Each time i have to open windows task manager & close it.Its time consuming :(

Comment: Agreed. I solved this by creating a .cmd file and use `taskkill` to close the processes of bluestacks and `net stop` to stop the services. You need to run the .cmd file as admin each time, but it was a better option. But Emirjonb has a better solution, VirtualPC instead of bluestacks!